# Set the Segment control unselected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a problem, I want my `UISegment` controls to start all unselected when the app loads.

If someone can help on this matter I would be very thankful.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Either:

```
[mySegmentControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:-1];
```

or:

```
[mySegmentControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];
```

It's all in the apple docs too.
Ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html

Answer (score 3):

At the start after initializing your segmentedcontrol you can use

```
yourSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex=-1;
```

it will erase any selected index.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Just uncheck Selected checkbox from property